# Android Studio Blank Activity

Tags: android

I'm using Android Studio 2.1 and there is no Blank Activity option.
I've seen people asking about this, and the general advice was "make one yourself". 
The thing is that I know nothing about Android development so I'm following this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html that should take me through the basic steps (at least it seems that it will do that). So I'm trying to keep things in line with what they do there. 
So should I go with Empty Activity or Basic Activity? I tried them both and from what I undestand there are little differences between them, but Empty Activity sounds more like a clean startup activity than Basic. I don't know.
What should I do?

Comment: There is no difference in both actually. But anyways, you can download the old version of the studio by following link: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/stable

Comment: Just use the Basic Activity Template

Comment: I'd rather use the new version. I like to use the newest versions of the tools I have. I imagine that one could start with X Activity and get (in one way or another) to a Y Activity, if one knows what it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Empty Activity is the same as Blank Activity. It will gives you `.xml` file that will be your layout where you put your `Buttons` or `EditTexts` and `.java` file where you will code your activity.
But Basic Activity will gives you two `.xml` files, the `main_activity.xml` that contain `FloatingActionButton` and a `ToolBar` and it will include the second `.xml` where you will put your `Buttons` and one `.java` file . 
If you are new at android developing start with Empty Activity it's more simple to understand

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep things in line with what they do [there](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html), you should  go with *Basic Activity* because in the [third](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html) step of that tutorial you'll need `content_my.xml` which won't be generated if you choose *Empty Activity* at start (of course you can put your code in `activity_main.xml` which is pretty the same thing). So if you only want to go in line with the tutorial you choose *Basic Activity*. The difference between previous *Blank Activity* and current *Basic Activity* is the extra code generated in your activity like:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question so I've compared the old blank activity template (according to a video tutorial I watched) with the 'empty' and the 'basic' activities templates of the new Android Studio.

The empty activity has only 2 options: "Activity Name" and "Layout Name".

[image]

Meanwhile Basic activity has 4 options, just like the "blank activity" template of the old Android Studio version as you can see below:

[image]

[image]

So, I would go with the basic template and manage the extra code until I need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you go with BaseActivity, it is also kind of empty activity. It would have only a root element in its layout. So you can start with any of the Basic or Empty.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Activity comes with FloatingActionButton and menu layout. Empty Activity does not contain FloatingActionButton and menu xml layout, although you can add them manually when you feel so. What I feel is that Basic Activity is preferable because when you created Empty Activity and want to add menu in your activity it become rather difficult to add menu xml layout manually. I have personally encounter problems while adding menu xml manually.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Select File --> Settings

[image]

Select "Plugins" from that window

1.) Android NDK Support
2.) Android Support

check there any Tick Mark. Make Tick mark them, if no tick Marked . Then Rebuild Your App. or Close android studio and reopen